# Combinations without repeating pairings more than twice.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

How many groups of 10 can one make from 100 people if no pairing is repeated more than twice?

You are making teams for a series of icebreaking exercises.  You want to force patrons to meet other patrons, but you also want to allow a patron to bring a newly-made friend into a subsequent group (to help with anxiety and introducing one another)...but just once.  After that group you can take someone different to the next group, and so on.

But this restrictions applies to ALL members.  While 100 choose 10 is something like "full saturation" of every combination, this restriction is incredibly destructive: For example, Person A and B would normally be in 98 groups (AB_3 through AB_100) can instead now only be in 2 groups together.

I haven't been able to back into a formula for this.

Comment: I do not understand how you concluded that persons A and B can be in $98$ groups since a group including A and B is determined by which $8$ of the other $98$ people are in their group.

Comment: You are right @N.F.Taussig - I was assuming a 3 member group as illustrative.  Assuming A is 1, B is 2, and so on, your first group would be ABC and you'd have ABD, ABE, and so on until AB100.  So given the restriction of only 2 groups with AB at maximum, that would be a "loss" of 96 groups (ABE through AB100).  With a 10 person group, the elimination is far, far greater.  Thousands of groups would no longer be possible.

Answer (score 1):

A clear upper bound is $220$. If you have $n$ such groups of $10$, you form $n\binom{10}{2}=45n$ pairs of elements within the same groups. But this can be at most twice the number of pairs of elements between $1$ and $100$, i.e. $2\binom{100}{2}=9900$; so $n\le 9900/45=220$.

Here's a solution for $140$ groups, found by simulated annealing.

```
    4   29  31  37  39  40  41  65  66  83
    12  22  30  34  37  69  74  76  91  93
    8   51  58  60  66  72  80  82  84  95
    5   30  32  54  60  62  64  68  79  91
    13  22  38  40  59  71  87  92  94  100
    4   7   32  49  50  61  67  74  77  80
    5   7   10  41  55  79  82  86  88  100
    6   21  30  36  40  48  61  92  95  96
    17  36  47  54  63  73  76  85  90  96
    10  45  51  54  56  61  63  66  88  94
    1   8   22  27  39  46  63  64  75  88
    1   2   5   14  18  24  30  57  63  72
    17  42  45  77  80  83  90  92  95  97
    4   5   9   20  35  43  47  51  87  89
    30  33  39  58  78  80  82  85  88  96
    3   5   9   11  22  37  48  56  57  88
    2   27  28  31  34  36  60  65  81  100
    22  23  26  38  51  54  64  67  78  86
    20  21  29  32  38  41  54  57  70  80
    15  27  31  32  42  48  69  78  84  87
    6   12  16  25  29  62  87  95  96  100
    16  24  38  50  56  76  77  79  82  84
    4   26  29  33  42  59  60  63  76  93
    2   6   15  19  33  50  53  79  83  88
    12  13  30  35  38  45  66  69  73  98
    6   13  32  34  50  58  63  64  72  89
    4   23  34  45  56  57  59  82  98  100
    26  30  44  46  56  60  65  71  87  90
    4   10  15  21  24  53  72  78  91  94
    3   5   16  33  45  58  74  84  94  99
    3   4   6   11  13  54  71  74  82  85
    18  27  33  36  37  43  50  54  71  84
    1   17  19  25  48  51  72  73  74  77
    1   7   12  19  31  56  62  67  73  92
    2   7   9   14  38  39  40  48  72  93
    11  15  16  22  32  57  58  65  92  99
    1   4   22  24  44  56  58  61  81  96
    35  41  44  62  65  69  74  85  97  99
    8   11  23  27  33  61  62  73  82  87
    7   21  30  37  42  44  64  66  81  100
    18  21  32  43  70  73  81  86  88  97
    18  20  25  31  32  39  67  76  78  92
    13  23  30  31  33  41  63  77  86  90
    9   10  13  15  39  61  65  67  90  95
    9   35  45  49  54  60  91  92  96  100
    10  11  19  34  40  47  56  63  68  98
    11  12  32  41  52  72  75  81  84  96
    3   13  36  41  42  53  58  60  73  87
    10  18  19  29  38  39  47  74  84  92
    8   13  15  19  24  37  50  76  81  99
    4   16  17  19  36  49  63  67  75  93
    3   8   10  28  34  44  51  52  84  92
    5   7   13  24  36  65  70  78  92  98
    2   4   37  65  68  75  84  86  87  95
    2   4   7   11  35  46  48  51  76  90
    1   8   16  25  36  37  49  59  86  89
    2   10  23  25  57  62  66  71  74  80
    7   34  42  45  53  61  70  71  75  76
    10  21  24  68  75  83  85  93  99  100
    28  30  40  42  57  68  73  84  88  93
    26  35  36  39  56  72  80  87  89  97
    1   11  18  37  46  68  70  80  94  100
    5   10  14  18  27  54  58  62  65  76
    2   13  18  44  45  52  60  79  85  86
    15  20  55  60  62  75  81  83  86  94
    15  28  29  43  64  77  82  87  92  93
    14  15  28  47  58  61  71  86  97  98
    8   20  28  38  42  48  94  96  97  98
    1   2   6   26  43  54  67  68  94  99
    16  31  34  37  52  54  55  61  72  87
    5   29  37  45  51  71  73  75  78  97
    19  20  26  27  52  57  61  77  91  99
    7   13  17  21  26  27  47  52  88  97
    1   3   28  54  66  70  75  79  95  99
    1   4   9   15  21  26  36  45  62  95
    5   22  25  27  32  40  44  53  75  82
    2   10  11  30  38  55  59  71  76  81
    12  13  14  16  23  28  81  88  89  91
    7   29  55  56  64  73  80  84  85  94
    2   17  28  39  51  59  69  82  91  99
    7   12  15  25  27  39  44  45  63  79
    1   23  27  29  34  48  58  79  85  91
    1   11  13  16  20  47  66  69  78  83
    19  21  34  35  42  59  75  78  80  96
    12  14  35  36  57  61  79  83  84  90
    14  16  35  39  53  54  56  74  95  100
    3   12  18  59  65  68  72  77  85  88
    11  38  53  61  63  65  73  79  80  100
    9   17  18  28  30  50  67  80  83  87
    1   6   12  23  39  43  52  76  97  100
    19  20  23  24  55  65  69  71  80  93
    3   22  33  34  35  47  55  60  67  93
    9   25  36  38  41  43  56  81  85  93
    9   29  42  47  49  54  65  72  82  86
    2   3   12  20  21  27  37  49  56  77
    6   7   9   16  23  28  32  53  60  85
    8   9   11  29  40  62  69  79  90  97
    6   8   34  38  44  70  77  78  86  89
    2   21  22  52  53  74  82  83  89  98
    5   6   17  44  55  61  68  76  92  98
    2   5   8   15  33  42  47  66  85  100
    15  16  20  29  44  66  68  71  72  96
    8   10  20  23  41  52  58  64  67  70
    8   14  19  26  43  45  53  55  78  85
    3   7   18  29  63  78  81  83  91  98
    6   14  46  49  51  81  87  93  94  97
    25  37  47  48  52  58  70  88  92  94
    2   3   8   17  24  29  31  61  69  75
    4   28  32  33  39  43  52  66  90  94
    3   19  39  45  48  57  64  69  81  87
    1   20  50  51  74  88  90  91  92  93
    6   24  26  31  38  46  47  49  57  82
    3   9   16  24  26  59  73  83  86  92
    7   34  41  49  51  68  69  71  83  96
    10  12  20  31  40  50  85  86  90  98
    7   18  36  46  58  59  66  75  77  97
    33  36  44  46  55  57  70  72  74  98
    6   17  18  24  33  35  41  48  71  98
    12  40  41  44  47  57  59  67  94  95
    23  25  49  53  81  84  89  90  98  99
    22  26  39  50  51  61  62  70  81  85
    16  18  21  31  35  44  73  82  93  94
    41  43  48  49  59  60  63  68  74  95
    6   11  14  29  36  45  52  67  86  99
    5   25  31  42  46  52  83  85  91  95
    24  30  34  39  41  46  53  54  77  84
    14  24  37  43  44  47  59  64  80  90
    3   19  32  62  82  89  90  91  94  96
    1   28  45  47  64  65  76  83  89  96
    9   14  46  66  68  73  74  76  78  89
    19  21  22  25  41  66  76  79  87  98
    6   28  35  37  57  58  62  63  77  78
    22  46  48  52  55  59  65  73  79  89
    5   23  31  50  56  66  70  93  96  97
    2   13  25  26  35  40  42  55  64  91
    15  40  43  63  67  69  70  84  89  100
    10  14  26  32  33  44  69  73  77  95
    14  23  32  37  38  42  51  55  63  99
    3   17  27  35  43  46  50  53  72  95
    9   10  13  17  31  53  59  70  96  99
```